# Generic parameter "Element" could not be inferred -- Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

So I'm in an Xcode playground, trying to remove the last character from a string. I think it should be really simple, but my code isn't working.

```
let test = "Get rid of that L"
Array(test.characters).dropLast().joinWithSeparator("")
```

I get an error on the second line "Generic parameter "Element" could not be inferred"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need the join bit, just do this:

```
let lastCharRemoved = String(test.characters.dropLast())
```